# Does std::shared_ptr<X> have a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I am learning `std::shared_ptr`.
I read a document about constructors of `shared_ptr` to find its copy constructor.

I could find a constructor,

```
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr& r );
```

but it seems it is not a simple copy constructor I expected,

```
shared_ptr( shared_ptr& r );
```

and it seems it does not shares reference counter.

Why `shared_ptr` does not have a simple copy constructor?

In case, I write what I really want to do below,

```
class A {
public:
    A(shared_ptr<X>& sptr) : sptr_(sptr) {}
private:
    shared_ptr<X> sptr_;
};
```

Comment: Copy constructors *usually* have the `const` part (because it should not modify the passed object), but doesn't need it.

Comment: You are expecting the wrong thing. A copy constructor in C++ usually takes a *constant* (hence `const`) reference, since it is not supposed to modify the thing being copied.

Comment: @filmor : thank you for comment. Does this copy increments reference counter of the original shared_ptr instance?

Comment: The reference counter (as well as the actual object) are shared (hence the name), i.e. none of the individual `std::shared_ptr` instances contains the object or counter, instead they all contain a pointer to this shared struct and update the reference count on constructing / destructing.

Comment: @filmore : thank you for telling me the mechanism.

Comment: Your API will be much clearer if you take `sptr` by value and move it into `sptr_`. Then there's no need for the caller to provide an lvalue pointer, and if an rvalue is passed no copy is performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why shared_ptr does not have a simple copy constructor?

The standard says that:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, [...]

There is nothing such a *simple copy constructor*. `std::shared_ptr` has a perfectly valid copy constructor instead. It constructs a `std::shared_­ptr` object that shares ownership with the given one (if valid).